# My SQL Server PIVOT does not work as expected

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have the below data:

```
Id  names   namevalues
1   name1   first value1
1   name2   first value2
2   name1   second value1
2   name2   second value2
```

DDL is:

```
Declare @t table(Id int, names varchar(50),namevalues varchar(100))
Insert Into @t select 1,'name1','first value1'
Insert Into @t select 1,'name2','first value2'
Insert Into @t select 1,'name1','second value1'
Insert Into @t select 1,'name2','second value2'

select * from @t
```

Expected output is:

```
Id  name1           name2
1   first value1    first value2
2   second value1   second value2
```

My try:

```
SELECT *
FROM  @t AS src 
PIVOT ( 
    MAX(namevalues) FOR namevalues IN ([name1],[name2] ) 
) AS pvt
```

However, this is wrong. How do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are pivoting the `names` column, not the namevalues column, so

```
SELECT * 
FROM  @t AS src  
PIVOT (  
    MAX(namevalues) FOR names IN ([name1],[name2] )  
) AS pvt
```